# Braintree Payment Apple Pay, payout to PayPal

Tags: node.js, backend, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am implementing a solution where the shopper can make payments using Google Pay, Apple Pay, PayPal & Credit/Debit Cards. After the payment, our platform will hold money and transfer it to the PayPal account after 15 days after deducting our commission, etc. Braintree seems to be a good solution to get paid at a single point and we can transfer it to the merchant Paypal account after a hold period. BrainTree suggested using Hyperwallet for the same. I've gone through Braintree Docs and Hyperwallet I have the following queries

1. How payment is transferred to Hyperwallet from Barintree?
2. I've tried using the Hyperwallet tutorial to get money on PayPal sandbox, it seems like API worked but never get money on my Paypal account.

Comment: Hey, did you figured any way to see transfer in paypal sandbox ? or any conclusion you found ?